# Granting uri permissions for FileProvider gives SecurityException

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-permissions, android-securityexception

I have 2 apps - **Demo** and **Pro**. Demo has a content provider and when Pro is installed it needs to transfer all files from the demo provider.

**Demo app (provider):**

```
<provider
            android:name="***.provider.InternalStorageProvider"
            android:authorities="***.demo.storage.int.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:syncable="true"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/int_storage_paths" />

</provider>
```

**Pro app (consumer):**

- Experiment 1:

  ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = cr.openFileDescriptor(exposedFileUri, "r");
  FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
>   ***.provider.InternalStorageProvider from
>   ProcessRecord{9c85875 10734:***/u0a61} (pid=10734,
>   uid=10061) that is not exported from uid 10062

- Experiment 2:

  Activity activity = getActivity();
  activity.grantUriPermission(activity.getPackageName(), exposedFileUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

  ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = cr.openFileDescriptor(exposedFileUri, "r");
  FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());

> java.lang.SecurityException: Uid 10061 does not have permission to uri
>   0 @ content://***.demo.storage.int.provider/db/file1

`InternalStorageProvider` is a copy of a normal `FileProvider`. But it doesn't matter as the execution cannot even reach it. Exceptions are thrown before it is called. 
Note that no chooser activities and intents are involved. The consumer tries to open the file from a known uri directly, without choosers. Most of the examples I've found are using `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` but I don't use an intent at all.

**How I am supposed to grant uri permissions to the consumer correctly?**

Comment: Running on this issue right now, by any chance you were able to solve it?

Comment: It was quite long ago, I barely remember anything. This stuff is real evil.

Comment: Solved it by passing `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to absolutely every other intent that was making use of the URI inside my app

Answer (score 1):

You need to give permission to pro app...

```
activity.grantUriPermission("pro app package name", exposedFileUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```